# Is it possible to run a search and replace on a webpack bundle after it's been transpiled?

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I want to run a regex and replace a bunch of url() image paths inside of the main-es5.js file after webpack has finished. Is there a way to run a search and replace post the transpiling?

All I fined are loaders that want to do it while the files are loading but my issue is I need to do it on the css after it's been compiled into the js file.